# In WMS service Geographic Coordinate System changed from NAD 1983 to WGS 1984

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-server, wms, map-service

In our project MXD it's Geographic Coordinate System is "NAD1983" and Projected Coordinate system is "NAD_1983_BLM_Zone_11N", and I published Map and WMS service from this MXD, while publishing in capabilities I checked mark on both Mapping  and WMS. After publishing services I opened both services in separate blank MXDs for Map service Geographic Coordinate System and Projected Coordinate system are same as source MXD but in WMS service Geographic Coordinate System changed to WGS_1984 and for Projection it showing supported coordinate system are WGS_1984, NAD_1983_BLM_Zone_11N. I am not getting why in WMS service Geographic Coordinate System changed to WGS_1984? Although in source MXD layer and dataframe has same GCS and PCS.

Comment: WMS almost always supports EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) in addition to whatever else you've set.

Comment: @mkennedy - But why in WMS service GCS changed from NAD1983 to WGS84.

Comment: It didn't. It still supports NAD 1983 BLM Zone 11N which is based on NAD 1983. It also supports WGS 1984 so someone can request the service in either coordinate reference system.